# unable to creating connection with ooyala videoplaza api

Tags: php, curl, ooyala

I am trying to create connection or call any api with ooyala videoplaza api through php curl but it's return me login page.
I have "x-o-api-key" key.
I have refere links are : [link1](http://help.ooyala.com/video-advertising/oadtech/ad_serving/dg/rest_api_authentication.html), [link2](http://www.help.ooyala.com/video-advertising/oadtech/ad_serving/dg/rest_targeting_template_api_examples_template_requests.html)

**php curl code :**

```
<?php
$method  = "GET";       
$data = "?x-o-api-key=myapikeyhere";
    $request = "https://api.videoplaza.com/api/1.0/campaign?status=upcoming&state=enabled".$data;

    $ch = curl_init($request);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, $method);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Length:50'));       
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json'));
    $output = curl_exec($ch);
print_r($output);

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not so familiar with PHP but I think you should be sending `x-o-api-key` as a HEADER field (and not as data to the request).